# Who needs to check a m'zuza?

Tags: mezuzah, inspection, safrus

I have heard that a *m'zuza* must be checked twice every seven years by a qualified *sofer*. I have also heard that, assuming it's known to have been *kosher* at one point, it need only be checked for faded or cracked letters thereafter, and that that check can be done even by a layman who knows what the letters look like (provided he take any questionable *m'zuza* to a *sofer* for expert checking). Which is correct? Sources please.

Comment: Which skills will a qualified sofer use except his knowledge of what the letters look like?

Comment: @DoubleAA, perhaps things like how much fading is acceptable vs. a problem, how much of a change constitutes a crack (naked eye? magnifying glass?), etc.

Comment: @MonicaCellio yes, though (as I'll edit into the question) someone unsure would then take the _m'zuza_ to a _sofer_.

Comment: If he's qualified enough to never kasher a posul one, what could be the problem?

Comment: @DoubleAA, what could be? I don't know. One possibility, I suppose, is a rule that only someone with the _safrus_ equivalent of _sh'chita_'s _kabala_ can check _m'zuzos_. Beats me.

Comment: @msh210 there is certainly such a thing as Kabbalah wrt Safruth, but I am not familiar enough with the subject to know if a non-Sofer may check. The possible existence of such a rule has never occurred to me personally (though I wouldn't base an answer on that).

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/28380

Answer (score -2):

I am a certified sofer. I will tell you my opinion. First I would like to ask you to take a look at my website, particularly at my blog, Diary of a Sofer. I have digital pictures of many shailos that come up. Most days I see shailos, either in mezuzos, tefillin, or where mezuzos are put. Many of the shailos are in mezuzos that have been checked. Sometimes people have missed some pretty incredible things, as you will see if you follow my blog. If you have high quality mezuzos, and those mezuzos have been computer scanned, and they have been checked by a certified sofer, and you don't have any special problems with the writing, it is possible that you may do a fine job. There are two problems however, that I see. One, you may not know keses hasofer, and mishna berura on these inyonim. There are some central halachos that you need to know before you work with mezuzos, or you can end up posseling something, and never knowing it. If you are never planing on touching a knife or a pen, you certainly have less chance of messing up, but I couldn't recommend it unless you were familiar with the main halachos of stam. I don't mean you have to take a test on the halachos of how to make dio, but you should know what chok tochoks, sho ksidran, kiddush Hashem, mukaf gvil, and leshma are. I just can't believe that without knowing the basics of those halachos that mistakes won't be made. My website is mezuzadepot.com and you will see many shailos there.

Comment: Did this advertisement answer the question at all?

Comment: I think he's saying that an average person would probably do ok checking them himself if he at least knows the certain rules he listed. I have no idea though how knowing what shelo kisidran, kiddush hashem, chok tochos or leshma are will help one check. Mukaf gevil I accept you should know, but it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Certainly much of the advertising should be removed, as well as the extended discussion about the many many mistakes he finds in checked mezuzot which you can read about elsewhere, which does little more than try and scare a new checker without any precise basis.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't see how _mukaf g'vil_ is necessary knowledge, considering that an assumption in the question is that the _m'zuza_ was once valid.

Comment: @msh210 If a letter touches the edge of the klaf because the paint expands (say through heat) then it needs to be separated before use because of mukaf gvil. (There's also related rules about big and small holes in the klaf and letters touching each other.)

Comment: @DoubleAA, oh, okay, I was unaware paint would expand so much as to cause that. (Maybe that means I should bring my _m'zuzos_ to a _sofer_. `:-)`)

Comment: @msh It's not unheard of. (And you would notice it if you were looking at the letters. Just make sure each letter is fully surrounded by white klaf.) It might also expand from water damage or even the slow absorption of the klaf. I even heard a case once where someone cut off the extra klaf at the bottom of the mezuzah, but they ended up nicking the bottom of the very last letter: Tzadi Sofit. This is an equivalent problem as above and can be solved by scratching off a small part of the leg adjacent to the edge (provided the leg is not too small as to make the overall letter unrecognizable).

Comment: @DoubleAA, that (last solution you mention) wouldn't be _chak tochos_ (or the singular, _chak tavech_ (??))?

Comment: @msh210 Wait, my bad; I knew something was off. I mixed up the case. The rule of mukaf gevil is only me'akeiv at the moment of writing. The case I mentioned about ripping the mezuzah was the example I was given where it is kosher m'ikar hadin, but we "fix" it anyway because the next person won't know.

Comment: @msh210 But either way, it isn't Chak Tochot because the shape of the letter was essentially there; it was just missing mukaf gevil. Just like how we separate letters that are touching each other.

Comment: But if you want a case where even me'ikar hadin you need to know about mukaf gevil: consider if you find a tiny hole in the klaf on the edge of a letter. You have to assume the original sofer didn't notice, and pasul the klaf as lacking mukaf gevil. If it was a big hole, you can assume he did notice and the ink spread.